# Wireshark not displaying GET or POST data

Tags: http, networking, get, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I'm a student and I'm taking my first networking class. I'm working on an assignment designed to get me used to using Wireshark and understanding packet transfers. Part of the assignment is to collect some data about a certain GET request, but my Wireshark isn't showing anything related to GET or POST requests.

I've discussed this with my instructor and he can't figure it out, either. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling Wireshark, but haven't gotten anything different.

Here's what I'm getting when I should be getting GET data:

```
26030 1157.859131000 128.119.245.12 10.0.0.7 HTTP 564 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found (text/html)
```

This is the first packet I get after connecting to the server (this comes from right-click "copy"). From what I've gathered from the assignment instructions and the instructor, this should get a GET request. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Gordon This isn't my server - it's connected to umass.edu and it's part of a larger tutorial introduction to Wireshark. In fact, I'm not even a student at UMass. This isn't the point, though - the page loads the way it is supposed to, even for the instructor and the other people in the course. I'm the only one experiencing this problem and we can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: That information is relevant, and should be in the original question. I'm going to guess that the URL you're attempting to access is http://gaia.cs.umass.edu/wireshark-labs/INTRO-wireshark-file1.html. The rest of the wireshark output is relevant, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a browser plugin like firebug to examine actual request and response headers being exchanged. Sometimes due to page caching actual document may not be refetched after only headers like if modified since since being exchanged or the browsers cached version has not expired.

Comment: Yes, but I have tried using other browsers I don't normally use and wouldn't have this (or any other) page in its cache and there are still no GET/POST packets coming through on Wireshark. The purpose of the assignment is to get accustomed to using Wireshark, and this question in particular (while very elementary) is to determine the amount of time it takes between sending the GET request and receiving the data, using the Wireshark application. I think there are larger implications, as subsequent assignments will use Wireshark and if I don't have full access, may not be able to complete them.